# Границы блока при абсолютном позиционировании

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать, чтобы блок со свойством position:absolute всегда имел ширину родительского контейнера bootstrap и находился ровно в его границах на всех устройствах?

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="position:absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Дать родительскому блоку position:relative

Блоку с absolute - width/height 100%

центровать можно: margin: 0 auto, или

```html
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Родит.контейнер бутстраповский, не хотелось бы менять его свойства

Comment: @ArturHan, а в чём проблема дописать? Сломаться вроде как ничего не должно. Да и если боитесь, что что-то наломаете, цепляйтесь по родительскому классу конкретно к этому элементу (.parent > .container).

Comment: И что за свойство width/height? Высота этого блока разная может быть

Comment: position:absolute подразумевает, что блок выходит из потока и никак не взаимодействует с его окружением. Все свойства позиционирования дадут результат привязки к вьюпорту, т.е. видимой части окна браузера. Poisiton:relative никак не поменяет поведение вашего родительского блока, но он даст понять дочеренему, что тот находится в его рамках :) на счет width/height я имел ввиду два разных свойства. Width - 100%; height: 100%; за рамки родителя он не убежит

Comment: Так же на счет центровки, на самом деле она не понадобится, если ширина и высота дочернего блока будет 100%. Вам останется дочерний блок явно привязать к сторонам, например - left: 0, top: 0;

Comment: Дело в том, что у .container position:fixed

Comment: Тогда скорее всего придется все дочерние элементы контейнера обернуть еще в один див. Уже ему дать relative и далее позиционировать по нему таким же способом

Comment: Не работает ваш код